# Need help in perline noise ursina to make an a plain land

Tags: unity-game-engine, perlin-noise

i understood using perlin-noise to make a pattern with cubes but what i want to is a random terrain
plain land such as this game called muck (that has been devolped by unity)[image]

i've tried doing:

```
noise = PerlinNoise(octaves=3, seed=2007)
amp = 3
freq = 24
width = 30


for po in range(width*width):
s = randint(200, 255)
q = Entity(model="cube", collider="box", texture="white_cube",
           color=color.rgb(s, s, s))
q.x = floor(po/width)
q.z = floor(po % width)
q.y = floor(noise([q.x/freq, q.z/freq]) * amp)
```

so this would give a -almost- perfect random terrain but i want my terrain look more realistic than cubic
thanks in advance ;)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show us your code in the form of a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Also what does this have to do with `python` and `pygame`? I removed these tags as they seem not relevant to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unsurprisingly, your landscape looks cubic because you're constructing it from cubes. So to make it more realistic, use a more flexible [Mesh](https://www.ursinaengine.org/cheat_sheet_dark.html#Mesh) for it. You will have to assign each point of the surface separately and connect it to its surrounding via triangles:

```py
level_parent = Entity(model=Mesh(vertices=[], uvs=[]), color=color.white, texture='white_cube')

for x in range(1, width):
    for z in range(1, width):
        # add two triangles for each new point
        y00 = noise([x/freq, z/freq]) * amp
        y10 = noise([(x-1)/freq, z/freq]) * amp
        y11 = noise([(x-1)/freq, (z-1)/freq]) * amp
        y01 = noise([x/freq, (z-1)/freq]) * amp
        level_parent.model.vertices += (
            # first triangle
            (x, y00, z),
            (x-1, y10, z),
            (x-1, y11, z-1),
            # second triangle
            (x, y00, z),
            (x-1, y11, z-1),
            (x, y01, z-1)
        )

level_parent.model.generate()
level_parent.model.project_uvs() # for texture
level_parent.model.generate_normals() # for lighting
level_parent.collider = 'mesh' # for collision
```

However, this will be quite slow to generate, mostly due to the Perlin noise implementation used (I'm assuming [this one](https://pypi.org/project/perlin-noise/)). A faster option can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42147776/producing-2d-perlin-noise-with-numpy).